# How to modify CSV format data using pandas in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am reading a CSV file into variable called 'data' as follows  in Jupyter Notebook using pandas

---

`import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/hp/Desktop/dv project/googleplaystorecleaned.csv")`

---

I tried to modify the 'Size' column of the [data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PINV.png) to remove the character 'M' and 'k' using the following code

```
for i in range(len(data['Size'])):
    data['Size'][i]=str(data['Size'][i])
    data['Size'][i]=data['Size'][i].replace('M','')
    data['Size'][i]=data['Size'][i].replace('k','')
    data['Size'][i]=data['Size'][i].replace('Varies with device','')
    data['Size'][i]=float(data['Size'][i])
print(data['Size'])
```

The code seems to work only partially on the data set as i am getting the following output

```
0                        19
1                        14
2                       8.7
3                        25
4                       2.8
                ...        
10836                   53M
10837                  3.6M
10838                  9.5M
10839    Varies with device
10840                   19M
Name: Size, Length: 10829, dtype: object
```

Please tell a proper way to do so.

Comment: Are you just trying to extract the numbers? If so just use some regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an example dataframe to show the result :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,1], 'B': [3,4,3], 'Size': ['Ma2','kb3','3l Varies with device po']})
for i, v in enumerate(df['Size'].values):
    v = v.replace('M', '')
    v = v.replace('k', '')
    v = v.replace('Varies with device', '')
    df['Size'].values[i] = v
print(df)
```

Before :

```
    A   B   Size
0   1   3   Mfoobar1
1   2   4   kfoobar2
2   1   3   Varies with devicefoobar3
```

After :

```
    A   B   Size
0   1   3   foobar1
1   2   4   foobar2
2   1   3   foobar3
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can also try this:

```
import pandas as pd
list1= ['20M','9M','10K','10']
dataframe1=pd.DataFrame(data=list1,columns=['Size'])

for i, s in enumerate(dataframe1['Size']):
    if s[len(s)-1]=='M':
        dataframe1['Col1'][i]=dataframe1['Size'][i].replace('M',"")
    if s[len(s)-1]=='K':
        dataframe1['Col1'][i]=dataframe1['Size'][i].replace('K',"")


dataframe1
```

You will get your expected output.

Note: You can add if condition according to your requirements